# Array Index Out of Bounds - Class Name Convenction

Tags: java, arrays, exception, terminal

I'm using the terminal in Mac to try and output some strings using javac. However there are some symbols that don't seem to work, for instance the dollar sign and asterisk:

```
public class BirdDisplay{
    public static void main(String... args){
    System.out.println(args[1]);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
javac BirdDisplay.java
java BirdDisplay sparrow $someBird
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at BirdDisplay.main(BirdDisplay.java:3)
```

As far as I know $ is accepted in class names and is a valid identifier, what is the cause of this exception?

Comment: It's because you are not sending the expected arguments with your application launch command. Call `java BirdDisplay "arg1" "arg2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using it from a shell, where `$` is doing environment/shell variable substitution. This has nothing to do with Java - it's how the shell is invoking the process.

Just put it in single quotes:

```
java BirdDisplay sparrow '$someBird'
```

Note that the use of a `$` as a valid Java identifier is irrelevant, as you're not using it in any source code - the value `$someBird` *purely* being used as data in your program (or will be once you've prevented the shell from performing variable substitutions).

Answer (score 1):

As Daisy pointed out, this is because you are running your program in the shell, where `$someBird` is interpreted as an environment variable. Because `$someBird` is not an environment variable, the shell replaces it with nothing and you have a command-line arguments array of length 1 instead of length 2. As such, your program has no value for `args[1]` and you get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can test this by running this code to print out the length of `args`:

```
public class BirdDisplay{
    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
}
```

And now when you do:

```
javac BirdDisplay.java
java BirdDisplay sparrow $someBird
```

You will see `1` instead of `2`